# Configure aws SDK in PHP laravel

Tags: php, laravel, sdk, aws-sdk

Can anyone help me how to configure aws SDK in PHP laravel.
I referred the official GitHub repository of SDK but AWS class not found exception is being raised. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS SDK is an external PHP package and needs to be installed inside the project using `composer`. It comes with Laravel pre-packaged, so running `composer install` will solve the problem for you.

Navigate to your project root directory (where composer.json is placed)
`composer install`